# Improve RGBA render to texture transparency quality in openg es 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I've created a 2d interactive particle system. Only one thing left to do but I don't know how to do it, so I'd like to get some help.

```
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA , texW, texH, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA , GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE   , null);
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, texW, texH, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5   , null);
```

If I render it to `GL_RGB` with `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5` it looks like this:

[image]

If I render it to `GL_RGBA` with `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` it looks like this:

[image]

My question is what is the best way to achive quality like the first pics but still able to see things under it. I tried with other RGBA formats and data types but it only resulted black screen. It seems that the RGBA version turns everything completly transparent if the `gl_FragColor.a` is not 1.0.